# using ajax with java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, serversocket

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    data: "koala",
    url: "http://localhost:555",
    cache: false,
    success: function(result)
    {       
    },
    failure: function()
    {
    }
});
```

what will the syntax be to get the value i just sent though with ajax in my java? how will i get the value "koala". assuming you have accpeted the clientSocket connection

Answer (score 0):

data accepts a dictionary. i think you have to write something like

```
data: {"koala": "koala"},
```

then your server can get and manipulate the data with the variable name "koala". what the server send back is stored in parameter result.

Comment: well wanted as code in Java that will output the word koala sent by ajax

Answer (score 0):

Using JAX-RS and Jersey your backend would be something like this

```
@Path("/")
public class MyResource {


    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Animal createAnimal(final String animalName) {
        return dao.create(animalName);
    }
}
```

Sring MVC is quite similar as well.